# EaselJS not updating the stage with one than more object instance

Tags: easeljs

I must be doing something wrong, but when I add more than one instance of clock object, the setTime() stops working. 
You can just wrap this into html and body tags to see what I am talking about.
here is the code:
`

```
        function Clock(){
            this.SIZE=20;
            this.width=this.SIZE*2;
            this.height=this.SIZE*2;
            this.time=null;
            this.hourH=null;
            this.minuteH=null;
            this.initialize();
        }
        Clock.prototype = new createjs.Container(); 

        Clock.prototype.initialize = function () {

              var back = new createjs.Shape();

              var clockColor=createjs.Graphics.getRGB(220, 220, 220);
                var g = back.graphics;
                    g.setStrokeStyle(1);
                    g.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(240, 240, 240));
                    g.beginFill(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255,255,255));
                    g.drawCircle(this.SIZE, this.SIZE, this.SIZE);
                    g.endStroke();
                    g.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(230, 230, 230));
                    g.drawCircle(this.SIZE, this.SIZE, this.SIZE*0.85);
                this.addChild(back);    
                this.hourH=new createjs.Shape();
                this.minuteH=new createjs.Shape();
                this.addChild(this.hourH);
                this.hourH.x=this.hourH.y=this.minuteH.x=this.minuteH.y=this.SIZE;
                this.addChild(this.minuteH);
                this.hourH.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3, "round", "round");
                this.hourH.graphics.moveTo (0, 0);
                this.hourH.graphics.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB("black"));
                this.hourH.graphics.lineTo(0, -this.SIZE*0.6);
                this.hourH.graphics.endStroke();
                this.minuteH.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3, "round", "round");
                this.minuteH.graphics.moveTo (0,0);
                this.minuteH.graphics.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB("black"));
                this.minuteH.graphics.lineTo(0, -this.SIZE*0.7);
                this.minuteH.graphics.endStroke();
                this.setTime(3, 45);

        }
            Clock.prototype.setTime=function(hour, minutes){
                this.hourH.rotation=Math.min(hour, 12)/12*360;
                this.minuteH.rotation=Math.min(minutes, 60)/60*360;
            }

        function init(){ 
            createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30); 
            createjs.Ticker.addListener(function() {

            })

            stage = new createjs.Stage("clocks");
            myClock1=new Clock();
            myClock2=new Clock();
            myClock2.x=myClock2.y=50;
            stage.addChild(myClock1);
            stage.addChild(myClock2);
            myClock1.setTime(7,25);
            stage.update();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<div id="canvas_wrap">
    <canvas id="clocks" width="960" height="560"> </canvas>    
</div>
```

Comment: what's `setTime`? It's not part of the `Container` class of Easel.JS: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html

Comment: I posted the answer, but the next time you ask someone to try your code, please post a complete html-construct, that was like 4 additional lines ;-)

Comment: I tried to post the complete code, but for some reason the opening html, script, and body tags were not parsed as code within the ' '. ;) thanks for the answer! crazy javascript prototyping chain....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the initialize-method for the Container-Prototype as well, so your Clock-header should look like this:

```
function Clock() {
    this.initialize();
}
Clock.prototype = new createjs.Container(); 

// get the original initialize-method
Clock.prototype.container_init = Clock.prototype.initialize;

Clock.prototype.initialize = function () {
    // invoke the original method as the first thing before doing ANYTHING else
    this.container_init();

    // now you can do the other stuff
    this.SIZE=20;
    this.width=this.SIZE*2;
    this.height=this.SIZE*2;
    ...
```

I tested it, it worked for me with your code.